# How to get SelectedItem from ComboBox if i put as ItemSource ArrayList object

Tags: c#, combobox

```
ArrayList al=new ArrayList();
for(int i=0;i<lista.Count;i++){
    al.Add(new {Name=lista[i]});
}
comboBox.ItemsSource="al";
comboBox.DisplayMemberPath="Name";
```

How do I get `SelectedItem` from my `ArrayList`? I put the string value in my `ArrayList` Name and I've tried with cast string,

Comment: add a tag if winforms..

Comment: `lista` is `List<string>` isn't it?

Comment: I did it now with Dictionary<int,string> I don't know hot to get it with ArrayList I tried to cast with object string List but nothing doesnt work